# Bad magic number while trying to mount a new hard disk

Tags: rhel, mount, ext4, xfs, superblock

Im using RHEL 8.7
I've added new HD `nvme0n2` to my linux and created partititions successfully

the output of `lsblk -f`

> NAME       FSTYPE LABEL                  UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
> nvme0n2
> ├─nvme0n2p1
> │          xfs                           5d966f3d-7aca-4f06-bf74-aa32d97aba76
> └─nvme0n2p2
> ext4                          56f6e1d8-58f3-47c7-840b-c1eebc24c3f7

But when I try to mount that hard disk `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n2 /mnt/newHardDrive/`  , it says

> mount: /mnt/newHardDrive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

when i tried checking in `/var/log/messages`, it shows:

> kernel: XFS (nvme0n2): Invalid superblock magic number

I also tried replacing the superblock using the backup superblocks with the command `sudo fsck -b 32768 /dev/nvme0n2`

But then I get this error:

> fsck from util-linux 2.32.1
> e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
> fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n2
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
> filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
> filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
> is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
> e2fsck -b 8193 
> or
> e2fsck -b 32768 
> Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvme0n2

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t mount the device as a whole, you need to mount individual partitions:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n2p1 /mnt/newHardDrive/
```

Comment: but I've read somewhere that we can mount a CD ROM and USB device

Comment: But this isn’t a CD-ROM or a USB device.